# Python Xarray add DataArray to Dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

Very simple question but I can't find the answer online. I have a `Dataset` and I just want to add a named `DataArray` to it. Something like `dataset.add({"new_array": new_data_array})`. I know about `merge` and `update` and `concatenate`, but my understanding is that `merge` is for merging two or more `Dataset`s and `concatenate` is for concatenating two or more `DataArray`s to form another `DataArray`, and I haven't quite fully understood `update` yet. I've tried `dataset.update({"new_array": new_data_array})` but I get the following error.

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I've also tried `dataset["new_array"] = new_data_array` and I get the same error.

## Update

I've now found out that the problem is that some of my coordinates have duplicate values, which I didn't know about. Coordinates are used as index, so Xarray gets confused (understandably) when trying to combine the shared coordinates. Below is an example that works.

```
names = ["joaquin", "manolo", "xavier"]
n = xarray.DataArray([23, 98, 23], coords={"name": names})
print(n)
print("======")
m = numpy.random.randint(0, 256, (3, 4, 4)).astype(numpy.uint8)
mm = xarray.DataArray(m, dims=["name", "row", "column"], coords=[names, range(4), range(4)])
print(mm)
print("======")
n_dataset = n.rename("number").to_dataset()
n_dataset["mm"] = mm
print(n_dataset)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (name: 3)>
array([23, 98, 23])
Coordinates:
  * name     (name) <U7 'joaquin' 'manolo' 'xavier'
======
<xarray.DataArray (name: 3, row: 4, column: 4)>
array([[[ 55,  63, 250, 211],
        [204, 151, 164, 237],
        [182,  24, 211,  12],
        [183, 220,  35,  78]],

       [[208,   7,  91, 114],
        [195,  30, 108, 130],
        [ 61, 224, 105, 125],
        [ 65,   1, 132, 137]],

       [[ 52, 137,  62, 206],
        [188, 160, 156, 126],
        [145, 223, 103, 240],
        [141,  38,  43,  68]]], dtype=uint8)
Coordinates:
  * name     (name) <U7 'joaquin' 'manolo' 'xavier'
  * row      (row) int64 0 1 2 3
  * column   (column) int64 0 1 2 3
======
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (column: 4, name: 3, row: 4)
Coordinates:
  * name     (name) object 'joaquin' 'manolo' 'xavier'
  * row      (row) int64 0 1 2 3
  * column   (column) int64 0 1 2 3
Data variables:
    number   (name) int64 23 98 23
    mm       (name, row, column) uint8 55 63 250 211 204 151 164 237 182 24 ...
```

The above code uses `names` as the index. If I change the code a little bit, so that `names` has a duplicate, say `names = ["joaquin", "manolo", "joaquin"]`, then I get an `InvalidIndexError`.

Code:

```
names = ["joaquin", "manolo", "joaquin"]
n = xarray.DataArray([23, 98, 23], coords={"name": names})
print(n)
print("======")
m = numpy.random.randint(0, 256, (3, 4, 4)).astype(numpy.uint8)
mm = xarray.DataArray(m, dims=["name", "row", "column"], coords=[names, range(4), range(4)])
print(mm)
print("======")
n_dataset = n.rename("number").to_dataset()
n_dataset["mm"] = mm
print(n_dataset)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (name: 3)>
array([23, 98, 23])
Coordinates:
  * name     (name) <U7 'joaquin' 'manolo' 'joaquin'
======
<xarray.DataArray (name: 3, row: 4, column: 4)>
array([[[247,   3,  20, 141],
        [ 54, 111, 224,  56],
        [144, 117, 131, 192],
        [230,  44, 174,  14]],

       [[225, 184, 170, 248],
        [ 57, 105, 165,  70],
        [220, 228, 238,  17],
        [ 90, 118,  87,  30]],

       [[158, 211,  31, 212],
        [ 63, 172, 190, 254],
        [165, 163, 184,  22],
        [ 49, 224, 196, 244]]], dtype=uint8)
Coordinates:
  * name     (name) <U7 'joaquin' 'manolo' 'joaquin'
  * row      (row) int64 0 1 2 3
  * column   (column) int64 0 1 2 3
======
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-50863379cefe> in <module>()
      8 print("======")
      9 n_dataset = n.rename("number").to_dataset()
---> 10 n_dataset["mm"] = mm
     11 print(n_dataset)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    536             raise NotImplementedError('cannot yet use a dictionary as a key '
    537                                       'to set Dataset values')
--> 538         self.update({key: value})
    539 
    540     def __delitem__(self, key):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in update(self, other, inplace)
   1434             dataset.
   1435         """
-> 1436         variables, coord_names, dims = dataset_update_method(self, other)
   1437 
   1438         return self._replace_vars_and_dims(variables, coord_names, dims,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py in dataset_update_method(dataset, other)
    492     priority_arg = 1
    493     indexes = dataset.indexes
--> 494     return merge_core(objs, priority_arg=priority_arg, indexes=indexes)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py in merge_core(objs, compat, join, priority_arg, explicit_coords, indexes)
    373     coerced = coerce_pandas_values(objs)
    374     aligned = deep_align(coerced, join=join, copy=False, indexes=indexes,
--> 375                          skip_single_target=True)
    376     expanded = expand_variable_dicts(aligned)
    377 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py in deep_align(list_of_variable_maps, join, copy, indexes, skip_single_target)
    162 
    163     aligned = partial_align(*targets, join=join, copy=copy, indexes=indexes,
--> 164                             skip_single_target=skip_single_target)
    165 
    166     for key, aligned_obj in zip(keys, aligned):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py in partial_align(*objects, **kwargs)
    122         valid_indexers = dict((k, v) for k, v in joined_indexes.items()
    123                               if k in obj.dims)
--> 124         result.append(obj.reindex(copy=copy, **valid_indexers))
    125 
    126     return tuple(result)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in reindex(self, indexers, method, tolerance, copy, **kw_indexers)
   1216 
   1217         variables = alignment.reindex_variables(
-> 1218             self.variables, self.indexes, indexers, method, tolerance, copy=copy)
   1219         return self._replace_vars_and_dims(variables)
   1220 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py in reindex_variables(variables, indexes, indexers, method, tolerance, copy)
    234             target = utils.safe_cast_to_index(indexers[name])
    235             indexer = index.get_indexer(target, method=method,
--> 236                                         **get_indexer_kwargs)
    237 
    238             to_shape[name] = len(target)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2080 
   2081         if not self.is_unique:
-> 2082             raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
   2083                                     ' valued Index objects')
   2084 

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

So it's not a bug in Xarray as such. Nevertheless, I wasted many hours trying to find this bug, and I wish the error message was more informative. I hope the Xarray collaborators will fix this soon. (Put in a uniqueness check on the coordinates before attempting to merge.)

In any case, the method provided by my answer below still works.

Comment: Can you share a more complete example? There was a small regression that caused a similar error (now corrected). But it's not clear what's going on without seeing the source.

Comment: Are you using xarray v0.8.0? It had a bug that caused this error erroneously, now fixed in v0.8.1.

Comment: I've now updated to 0.8.1 and still getting the same error. I've tried the example code in @jetesdal's answer, and that works, but for some reason it still doesn't work in my own code. My own code is too huge (and too confidential) to paste on here; it'll take me a good while to write a short example.

Comment: Thanks, a bug report would be much appreciated. It appears that at least one of your arrays has duplicate values along one of its axes, which means it cannot be automatically aligned, which is part of what happens in merging/assignment as well as many other xarray operations. There may be tweaks we can do to make this work, though.

Comment: @Stephan that's a great guess on your part! One of my `DataArray` indeed has many duplicates along its (only) axis, but that's intentional. The array I'm trying to add has 3 dimensions, one of them is shared with the array that has duplicate values. I will try to produce a reproducible error now.

Comment: @Stephan OK the problem is that what I'm using as the index has duplicates, and that is **not** intentional. I'm updating my question right now.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to your detailed report, this issue has now been fixed in the latest release of xarray (v0.8.2).

We fixed the behavior in two ways:

1. Alignment operations between xarray objects now succeed even with non-unique indexes, as long as the non-unique indexes take on identical values on all objects.
2. If you attempt to align objects with non-unique indexes that are *not* identical, you now get an informative error message reporting the name of the index with duplicate values, e.g., `ValueError: cannot reindex or align along dimension 'x' because the index has duplicate values`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make sure that the dimensions of your new DataArray are the same as in your dataset. Then the following should work:

```
dataset['new_array_name'] = new_array
```

Here is a complete example to try it out:

```
# Create some dimensions
x = np.linspace(-10,10,10)
y = np.linspace(-20,20,20)
(yy, xx) = np.meshgrid(y,x)

# Make two different DataArrays with equal dimensions
var1 = xray.DataArray(np.random.randn(len(x),len(y)),coords=[x, y],dims=['x','y'])
var2 = xray.DataArray(-xx**2+yy**2,coords=[x, y],dims=['x','y'])

# Save one DataArray as dataset
ds = var1.to_dataset(name = 'var1')

# Add second DataArray to existing dataset (ds)
ds['var2'] = var2
```

Comment: This is the right solution, but note that you don't need to ensure anything about the dimensions of your new DataArray or the labels. Xarray will align it automatically when you insert it.

Comment: Thank you @jetesdal but my code still doesn't work. Yours does (when I copy-paste it). Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found one way to do it but I don't know if this is the canonical way or the best way, so please criticise and advise. It doesn't feel like a good way of doing it.

```
dataset = xarray.merge([dataset, new_data_array.rename("new_array")])
```